# Get the data between two months in ibatis

Tags: sql, oracle, ibatis

If I want to get the data between `March 2013` to `November`( for each month, all daily data
are to be summed up to make a monthly data), I thought what I did was correct.
But it gives me `186 rows`(all dates from `March` to `November`) of result instead of giving 
just `9` ( `9` months between the two).

And for some reason, I get only `1` data for `November`.

Could anyone fix this?

```
 SELECT 
     TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('201305','YYYYMM')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYYMM') AS MONTH
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY TO_DATE('201305', 'YYYYMM') + LEVEL - 1  <=  TO_DATE('201311', 'YYYYMM')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('201303','YYYYMM'),LEVEL-1), 'YYYYMM') AS Month
   FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('201303','YYYYMM'),LEVEL-1 ) <= TO_DATE('201311', 'YYYYMM');
```

Output:

```
Month
-------
201303
201304
201305
201306
201307
201308
201309
201310
201311
```